# Android:About Crash Handler By using Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: android, exception

I describe my project background.
It have many Activity，and have  login Activity,it is means i need save some msg.

- **I Need:**

  catch the all unCaughtException,save the excetionInfo. and than recovery activities if it is can do .if can't recovey activity,we should close the Application friendly and ReStart with loginInfo。
- **I Have Done**

  I use Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler,can catch the exception,but i can't recovery activities or close the Application friendly。
- **Have tried**

  I use the
- 1.ActiviryManager.restartPackage

  It can close the app effective，but can't restart.
- 2.android.os.Process.kill(android.os.Process.myPid())

  It can't close my App effective. the same as System.exit(0)
- 3.I try to finish all Activity,

  It is close App effective,i use alarm to restart App, but I find that it is seem that my app can't complete close before。

My English is poor，Here of heartfelt apology。if you have some idea,please tell me ,i thanks u so much。

Answer (score 0):

For finishing activities use 'Finish()'.

What I would suggest, instead of directly restarting the app, just don't finish the main Activity and use a simple intent to the next activity.

And whenever you feel like 'restarting' the application, you just finish the current activity without using any intent; by doing so, the only activity in the stack will be the main activity (the only you havent finished).

Just put any extra code on the 'onRestart()' method and you are good to go!

PS. I hope I understood properly.

Comment: When an exception occurs in main Thread, I use Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler try to catch it ,the main Thread will become can‘t work. I do anythings for UI(Main Thread ) ,does not work.